# Discretizing all attributes vs. discretizing only the class label

Tags: regression, machine-learning, categorical-data, dataset, discrete-data

I have a numeric dataset and I would like to apply classification algorithms on it. So I am using Weka's Discretize filter to convert the numeric values to discrete. However I wonder what can be the implications of converting all the attributes (including the class label) to discrete vs. converting only the class label to discrete.

Is there anyone who experienced such a scenario?